Is it possible to define a concrete object with language clearly and accurately?
How do we know whether counterexamples of a concept are infinite or finite? Is there an end to the process of revision?
It is usually claimed that defining a concept clearly and accurately is almost impossible since the boundaries of things are vague. Very often, that’s a spectrum.
For example, in different languages, the word “red” refer to different ranges of colours.
For some concrete objects, they may seem very clear. To take “book” as an example, I could say that it is a written or printed work which describes something or tells a story, and consists of pages glued or sewn together along one side and bound in covers.

Yet there’s one problem: one may provide counterexamples like e-books. When we are faced with counterexamples, of course we can revise the definition again and again to ensure we get a relatively clear and accurate definition.
But my question is, how do we know whether the counterexamples are infinite or finite?  Is there an end to the process of revision?

Prototype theory does a lot of work here: while an ebook is a type of book, when someone says an unqualified "book" listeners will generally only think of a paper book. (Of course that may change in the future...) The Natural Semantic Metalanguage is one modern attempt for explaining how languages mean and define things, taking prototypes and vagueness into account.

And words are language specific. There may be gaps when translating to another language, but that doesn't mean that "red" in English doesn't have a clear meaning: there are colours all would call red, others none would, and some transitional oranges/purples that are debated, but no one would include yellow under "red" as if English were a language with only three basic colour terms. The sorites paradox is interesting in philosophy, but not so much in linguistics.

All language is metaphoric. There is no one-to-one correspondence between language and things in the real world. There's always a gap. Language is its own thing, so to speak. Also, finite and infinite are not terms I would use to describe meanings as you have done with the idea of book.

@curiousdannii There are transitional oranges/purples that are debated. That’s why I consider “red” in English doesn’t have a clear definition.

@Robin As I said, look into Prototype theory. Definitions based on boundaries frequently don't work well, but definitions based on the centre of a category normally work very well. Vagueness of boundaries doesn't mean the centre is unclear.

Okay. I get your point now. I guess it’s just a problem of how we define “clear”
